# How to get private dictionary from instance using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Say there is a class definition in a 3rd party library, that I cannot modify. E.g.

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> InternalData { get; set; }

    // Public methods to modify InternalData
}
```

If I debug an application that has an instance of this class then I can see the private members of the instance, when I hover over the code and expand out the inspection dialog. This might be okay when I have a small Dictionary but if I have a large dictionary and I want to output it to a file or in the output window to debug something, then how can I do this?

I know reflection can enable me access to see private members but how is this achieved?

So if I wanted to use reflection to assign the internal Dictionary to my variable internalData below, then how is this done in this method example?

```
public void GetReflectedData()
{
    MyDataClass myData = new MyDataClass();

    // Call some methods to add data.

    // Reflection calls here

    Dictionary<string, int> internalData;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to get a `FieldInfo` that represents the field you want, using `BindingFlags.Private`.  You can then call `GetValue` on the `FieldInfo`, passing in the instance of the class that contains the field you want.

Comment: If you're trying to access private data, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: It sounds like this is just for debugging purposes.  As long as it stays that way, and doesn't become structural, it's probably ok.

Comment: You certainly can do this, but you really should think twice before doing it in production code, as the external library can change at any time. It's questionable for debugging, and almost never a good idea for real code.